# array python to php

Tags: php, python

I have to translate a python code to php, but I don't know how this python code work in php :

```
dec = data_ar[4:len(data_ar)]
```

I don't know what's the colon ":" between [ ]!
Thanks

Comment: Your Python code could be improved: `data_ar[4:]`

Comment: But colon is not used in the same case in php...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just [Python's array slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1427124), so I think what you want is [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
array_slice($data_ar, 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to achieve the exact functionality in PHP:

```
<?php
$data_ar = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$dec = array_slice($data_ar, 4, count($data_ar)-4);
```

Now, the interesting thing here is the `len(data_ar)`. If you provide the colon without a second argument, "until the end" is assumed. So this piece of functionality should actually have been written like so:

```
dec = data_ar[4:]
```

Likewise, we can modify the PHP side of things to reflect the same simplicity:

```
<?php
$data_ar = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$dec = array_slice($data_ar, 4);
print_r($dec); // Returns array(5,6,7)
```

Comment: As with his Python example, there's no need to recompute the length. `array_slice` goes to the end of the array by default. (Check the documentation.)

Comment: +1 for using [`print_r`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). Knowing about that function will probably help him a lot with debugging.

Comment: I just read your explanation and decided to (temporarily) change my +1 to -1 since this is wrong: _Offsets start at zero, so they're actually grabbing one more than the length of the list._ Read the link in my answer on Python array slicing and fix your answer. When you've fixed it I'll give back the +1!

Comment: i think maybe you're mis-understanding something here. are you a python programmer yourself? if `mystr = 'hiho'` and you print `mystr[1:]` `iho` is printed. nothing about my statement is incorrect.

Comment: @JoshuaBurns - I don't use Python much, but I know enough to know that your statement about going off the end of the list is wrong. As with a lot of other slicing functions, the first index arg is _inclusive_ and the second is _exclusive_. I.e. you _must_ specify an index that's one _after_ the last element you want.

Answer (score 0):

Colon means "to" in most languages. This means index 4 to the length of the array (the end).

In PHP, you can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) like this:

```
$dec = array_slice($data_ar, 4)
```